# Match correct version number from array of version using Composer API

Tags: php, arrays, composer-php

i am trying make a script which reads composer.json and loop through all of the items in "require" section and find there dependancies.

now suppose one of the entry in require section of composer.json is

```
"illuminate/database": "~5.1",
```

so if i want to install this package  i need to translate the version no "~5.1" or any other version format which we can use in composer.json to a fully qualified version no that matches a version no from : https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database

I am sure lots of you will be thinking that why i am trying to reinvent the wheel when i can use composer from console and install it.

i am trying to make web based package installer for my script that can work on shared hosting too where exec or proc_open is disabled,

my goal is to translate the version no from composer.json to a full version and download that package from github from my self.

i just need the version no which i can search in my array of all versions of that package.
Array to search in is like this:

```
Array
(
[dev-master] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/31531.json
    )

[5.3.x-dev] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/845026.json
    )

[5.2.x-dev] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/587699.json
    )

[5.2.39] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/867275.json
        [requires] => Array
            (
                [classpreloader/classpreloader] => ~3.0
                [doctrine/inflector] => ~1.0
                [jeremeamia/superclosure] => ~2.2
                [league/flysystem] => ~1.0

            )

    )

[5.2.38] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/861234.json
    )

[5.2.37] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/858228.json
    )

[5.2.36] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://packagist.org/versions/852102.json
    )
```

so i input version no "~5.1" to the function with the above array in whichit can look and return me the index from that array which may be like "5.2.39"

I know it is somehow possible to achieve using composer API , but i am unable to find the exact solution .The closest to solution i was :

```
$version="~5.1";
$parser=new \Composer\Semver\VersionParser();
$ret=$parser->parseConstraints($version);
```

which outputs

```
Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint Object
(
[constraints:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Composer\Semver\Constraint\Constraint Object
            (
                [operator:protected] => 4
                [version:protected] => 5.1.0.0-dev
                [prettyString:protected] => 
            )

        [1] => Composer\Semver\Constraint\Constraint Object
            (
                [operator:protected] => 1
                [version:protected] => 5.2.0.0-dev
                [prettyString:protected] => 
            )

    )

[prettyString:protected] => 5.1.*
[conjunctive:protected] => 1
```

)

but i don't know how to use the above result and select correct index from version array.
Hope i was clear in describing my question. And thank you in advance

Comment: Assuming you are requiring `~5.1`, and the available versions are `5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2-beta1` - what should be the result, and why?

Comment: result should be best matching version number( just like how composer matches)  for input version no (~5.1 this will be from composer.json)

Comment: Which version would you consider "best match"? You might already feel that this discussion will lead to me suggesting "If you need something that should work like Composer, why don't you directly use Composer?" Composer isn't just a CLI tool, it is also a package that can be included. And I'd highly suggest to do so because the next step after answering "which one is the best version for one package" will be answering "how can you match two packages which depend on each other", and so on - all that complex stuff that Composer already solved.